# Transforming/Filtering a list of custom objects to another using Guava collections

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, guava

I am trying to convert this below logic to possibly use Guava collections and cannot figure out which one suits best - filter or transform. Even if multi step how to ensure that the list on which filtering happens builts on itself.

```
Map<Long, Detail> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Detail detail : detailList) {
  if (map.containsKey(detail.getAppId())) {
      Detail currentDetail = map.get(detail.getAppId());
      if (detail.getCreatedOn().before(currentDetail.getCreatedOn())) {
          continue;
      }
  }
  map.put(detail.getAppId(), detail);
}
return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Where Detail is just a class with Long appId and Date createdOn.

Is it even possible to convert this specific logic to a Guava based one.

Explanation of the code: From the list of Detail objects, find the ones which are the most recently created ones per appId. If an appId has more than one detail, then pick only the latest one.

*Can use only Java 7*

Comment: This really isn't going to work as a view collection, which is what Guava offers built-in.  _Neither_ of those operations let you combine values in any way.  Your current approach is probably the best available as of Java 7.  (If you have Java 8 it might be a different story.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can somehow rewrite this code using filter or transform methods from Guava, but you can certainly benefit from other Guava methods.

First of all, using `Multimaps.index(Iterable<V> values, Function<? super V, K> keyFunction)` method you can clearly show that you want to break detailList into number of collections by appId:

```
Multimap<Integer, Detail> detailsByAppId = Multimaps.index(detailList,
        new Function<Detail, Integer>() {
          @Override
          public Integer apply(Detail detail) {
            return detail.getAppId();
          }
        }
);
```

Then you can iterate through this collection of collections and find the latest detail in each of them:

```
List<Detail> latestDetails = new ArrayList<Detail>();
for (Collection<Detail> detailsPerAppId : detailsByAppId.asMap().values()) {
  Detail latestDetail = Collections.max(detailsPerAppId, new Comparator<Detail>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Detail d1, Detail d2) {
      return d1.getCreatedOn().compareTo(d2.getCreatedOn());
    }
  });
  latestDetails.add(latestDetail);
}
return latestDetails;
```

Comment: Nice answer. But your code would be much shorter, clearer and more elegant if you used lambda expressions instead of anonymous classes for your `Function` and `Comparator`. The comparator could also be written  `Comparator.comparing(Detail::getCreatedOn)`.

Comment: @Lii you are right, but the author of the question didn't mention what version of java he is using and wanted to use filter or transform methods from Guava instead of Stream API so I assumed he is using Java 6 or 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can use only Java 7 and seems this is the only close answer i can get to.